# Angular equivalent of JQUERY/file upload/multipart form

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a simple file upload in my multipart form:

[image]

What I want to do is customize it so that it looks like this:

[image]

Although my first solution works fine - below is my code:

HTML snippet

```
            <div>
                <input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files)" />
            </div>
```

Controller snippet:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(files) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    console.log('test', files[0]);
    //Take the first selected file
    fd.append("file", files[0]);

    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined
        },
        transformRequest: angular.identity
    }).success('...all right!...').error('..damn!...');

};
```

I have very little control of the customisation for it to look like the second example.

I have thought about creating the button first seperately, then using jquery to store the file name into an input box like this:

> $("inputBox").html(filename);

but I am unsure on how to do this in angular or if this is the right way in solving the problem. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following is how you solve it:

1) Create a directive which gets file input value and replaces the value in the input box. In AngularJS DOM elements can only be manipulated this way.

```
//directive to add input file name in image upload
app.directive('imageupload', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).change(function() {
                // on change update upload file
                  $("#uploadFile").val($(element).val());
            });
        }
    };
});
```

2) HTML in view

```
            <input id="uploadFile" placeholder="Choose File" disabled="disabled" />
            <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
                <span>Upload</span>
                <input id="uploadBtn" imageupload type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files)" class="upload" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

3) CSS

```
/* upload */

.fileUpload {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
}
.fileUpload input.upload {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```